# How to automatically insert code for an Xcode video demo

Tags: xcode, scripting, macros, demo

I've been watching some of the WWDC 2009 videos which include some video demos in Xcode. The presenters are using some sort of macro or script bound to a keyboard shortcut to automatically insert some pre-prepared code at the current caret location. Each time they press the key, the next prepared snippet is inserted.

Does anybody know how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the presenters use [DemoAssistant](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/samplecode/DemoAssistant/index.html) which is Apple sample code.

It's a service that copies lines from a code file a line at a time.

Comment: Thanks, this seems ideal. It only does one line at a time, but I can modify that to insert multiple lines delimited by some string.